# Can we show a link to Android subscriptions page from our iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes

I'm working on an iOS app which shows the link(Manage subscription) to iTunes subscription URL if the user is subscribed to our product. We have iTunes In-App subscription integrated in our app.
But, the user could have subscribed via android or web too.
We would like to show a link and redirect our users to android subscriptions page or web subscriptions page where the user can manage his/her subscription.
The question here is, does apple restrict this "Showing android/web subscription page from our iOS app" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you are talking about app store review process you may want to check the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#trademarks-trade-dress).
Im pretty sure you CANT do this, not only because before submiting an app they ask you If you reference to any thid party trademark or product, also because I have never see an iOS app refering to an Android app, this is obvious taking into account Android is the main competitor of iOS.